# How do I configure the protocol layer of my packets Scapy?

Tags: python, scapy

I am reading packets from pcap files and sending them on my network. The trouble is I keep getting invalid checksum errors. I have set the packets to have a checksum of None in the IP layer (as Scapy auto generates any missing data) however I can't seem to do it for the Protocol Layer (TCP,UDP etc). Thus the checksum errors still occur.

**Example**

```
###[ IP ]### 
  version   = 4
  ihl       = 5
  tos       = 0x20
  len       = 436
  id        = 50116
  flags     = 
  frag      = 0
  ttl       = 107
  proto     = udp
  chksum    = None --- Correct as Scapy will Autogen
  src       = 169.254.162.71
  dst       = 169.254.208.208
  \options   \
###[ UDP ]### 
     sport     = 23616
     dport     = 23575
     len       = 416
     chksum    = 0x5f4a ---Incorrect Checksum
```

I have looked online and have found this:

```
pkt.payload.chksum = None
```

However that did not work.

```
pkt[Ether].src = "00:E0:4C:00:02:42"
pkt[Ether].dst = "00:E0:4C:01:08:99"
pkt[IP].src = "169.254.162.71"  # i.e new_src_ip="255.255.255.255"
pkt[IP].dst = "169.254.208.208"
pkt[IP].chksum = None
pkt.payload.chksum = None
pkt.show()
```

**Example Output**

```
###[ Ethernet ]### 
  dst       = 00:E0:4C:01:08:99
  src       = 00:E0:4C:00:02:42
  type      = IPv4
###[ IP ]### 
     version   = 4
     ihl       = 5
     tos       = 0x20
     len       = 436
     id        = 50116
     flags     = 
     frag      = 0
     ttl       = 107
     proto     = udp
     chksum    = None
     src       = 169.254.162.71
     dst       = 169.254.208.208
     \options   \
###[ UDP ]### 
        sport     = 23616
        dport     = 23575
        len       = 416
        chksum    = 0x5f4a ---Not set to None
```

Do note that the file I'm reading from uses all different types of protocols, so the solution should be generic if possible.

Comment: What do you mean "It did not work"? What did you do next. Could you share a code snippet ?

Comment: Yes sure. I have done that now

Answer (score 0):

`pkt.payload` is the IP layer. You're performing the same operation twice.

You should do:

```
pkt[IP].payload.chksum = None
```